How to write file to Docker Volume from Container with Python script
I have a python script that attempts to run open("util/file.json", 'w'), but am getting a PermissionError on "util/file.json". This is being run inside a Docker container with docker compose, and I am attempting to use a volume to store and persist the file.json. It seems like this has to do with permissions of course, but I have tried a couple things like a mount to my host computer with changed permissions, which works, but I would rather run directly in coordination with a named volume, so that I could run this container from another computer for instance without being totally binded to my current one. Thanks if anyone can help me solve this issue, I am fairly new to Docker so may be missing something very obvious.
Here is my part of my current Dockerfile:
WORKDIR /app

ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser

COPY . .

# This was an attempt to give proper permissions, didn't work
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /util \
 && chown -R appuser /util

# Switch to the non-privileged user to run the application.
USER appuser

# Run the application.
CMD python3 bot.py

And my compose.yaml
version: "1.0.0"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    user: appuser
    container_name: name
    volumes: 
      - some_util:/app/util

volumes: 
  some_util: 


I recommend connecting to the docker container after running it to see what's up.
docker container ls
docker exec --it dockerIDhere /bin/sh

does there already exist a file named file.json in your volume that might have incorrect permissions?

I'd suggest you to use VSCODE as ide if you are an intensive docker user. It is very easy to manage and monitor docker containers and it is easy to attach to them and print logs. This would help you enter in the container and check if the folders shared using docker compose are correctly located in the path you expect. This helped me quite a lot in the past with this kind of issues.

If you docker-compose run app ls -ld /app/util, what is the ownership of the mounted directory?
